# Symmetric monoidal structure on categorical nerves

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, symmetric-monoidal-categories

There are several notions of nerves, including nerves of categories, $2$-categories, and simplicial categories. These define functors
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{N}   &\colon \mathrm{Cats}_{(2,1)}                    \to (\infty,1)\text{-}\mathrm{Cats},\\
\mathrm{N}^2 &\colon \mathrm{Bicats}_{(3,1)}                   \to (\infty,1)\text{-}\mathrm{Cats},\\
\mathrm{N}^s &\colon \mathrm{sCats}^{\text{loc. Kan}}_{(2,1)} \to (\infty,1)\text{-}\mathrm{Cats}.
\end{align*}
Taking the appropriate nerves for each of these functors, we obtain $(\infty,1)$-functors from the $(\infty,1)$-categories of

- Categories, functors, and natural *isomorphisms*;
- Bicategories, pseudofunctors, *invertible* pseudotransformations, and *invertible* modifications;
- Simplicial categories, simplicial functors, and simplicial natural *isomorphisms*;

to the $(\infty,1)$-category of $(\infty,1)$-categories.

All of the $(\infty,1)$-categories involved become symmetric monoidal $(\infty,1)$-categories when equipped with the Cartesian product. Can we endow the above $\infty$-functors with a symmetric monoidal structure as well?

Also, if we don't truncate to $(2,1)$-categories, we get $(\infty,2)$-functors from the $(\infty,2)$-categories of categories or simplicial categories to that of $(\infty,1)$-categories. Can we make these two $(\infty,2)$-functors into symmetric monoidal $(\infty,2)$-functors between symmetric monoidal $(\infty,2)$-categories as well?

(I won't ask the same for the second case above, since I gather it wouldn't form a question admitting an answer at present, as $(\infty,3)$-categories, symmetric monoidal $(\infty,3)$-categories, and also Gray tensor products of $(\infty,2)$-categories are all currently developing subjects.)

Comment: Yes, all of these nerve functors preserve cartesian products. This is true already at the 1-categorical level. Whatever higher categorical formulations of this statement you might wish to make will follow from this basic 1-categorical fact.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Ah, lovely! Thank you!